# position menu bars below site logo css

Tags: html, css

so here is my mockup design:

[image: Here]

Below is my sample css:

```
.menu{
padding: 32px;
background-color: #cc6666;
opacity: 0.5;
filter: Alpha(opacity = 50); /* IE8 and earlier */
clear: both;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
```

But it isn't doing what looks like in my mockup. Need your help. Thanks.

UPDATE:

http://jsfiddle.net/qdhcQ/

Comment: What is `.menu`? What is "not doing what it looks like"? More information please.

Comment: Can you provide html and css codes in JSFIDDLE ?

Comment: like @str says, what does "not doing what it looks like" mean? What's wrong?

Comment: @xec it's not posing below the logo..

Comment: I don't see any logo?

Comment: Assuming I added the logo there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you added markup for logo.

So add in markup:

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

And in css

```
.logo
{
    height: 50px;
    background: brown;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/qdhcQ/6/)**

Comment: Assuming I have the logo there, your example is quite similar, but my mockup has some spaces below the menu..